# unsigned char and char XOR operation

Tags: c, types, xor

Is there anyone can help me to explain what is the difference between unsigned char and char in XOR operation?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char a[2] = { 0x56, 0xa5 };  // a[0]  0101 0110   
                                 // a[1]  1010 0101 
    a[0] = a[0] ^ a[1];          // a[0]  1111 0011    f3   
    printf("%02x", a[0]);
    puts("");

    unsigned char b[2] = { 0x56, 0xa5 }; // b[0]  0101 0110
                                         // b[1]  1010 0101 
    b[0] = b[0] ^ b[1];                  // b[0]  1111 0011    f3   
    printf("%02x", b[0]);
    puts("");
}
```

result:

```
fffffff3
f3
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

Another example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char a[2] = { 0x01, 0x0a };

    a[0] = a[0] ^ a[1];          
    printf("%02x", a[0]);
    puts("");

    unsigned char b[2] = { 0x01, 0x0a };       

    b[0] = b[0] ^ b[1];             
    printf("%02x", b[0]);
    puts("");
}
```

result:

```
0b
0b
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

Comment: Wrong type passed to `printf`. `%x` expects `unsigned`, you pass `int`

Comment: @Olaf: you are correct, but passing `(unsigned int)a[0]` would produce the same output.  An explanation is still required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, your code

```
printf("%02x", a[0]);
```

Passes a `char` value to a variadic function `printf`. The `char` value is promoted to `int` type and passed as such. The value of `a[0]` is `-13` because the `char` type happens to be signed by default on your environment, The value is preserved by the promotion as `int` and printf receives it as an `int`.

The format `%02x` expects an `unsigned int` value.  `printf` was passed an `int` value, an incorrect type invoking undefined behavior. Since `int` and `unsigned int` use the same parameter passing convention on your platform, this negative value of `-13` is interpreted as an `unsigned int` with the same bit pattern, with value `0xFFFFFFF3` because the `int` on your platform has 32 bits and negative values are represented in 2s complement.  The string produced by printf is `fffffff3`.  This behavior is not actually guaranteed by the C Standard.

In the second example, `b[0]` is an `unsigned char` with value `243` (`0xf3`). Its promotion to `int` preserves the value and the `int` passed to `printf` is `243`.  The same undefined behavior is invoked as `printf` is passed an `int` instead of an `unsigned int`.  In your particular case, the conversion performed by `printf` yields the same value, which printed as hex with at least 2 digits padded with leading `0`s gives `f3`.

To avoid this ambiguity, you should either cast the operand as `unsigned char`:

```
printf("%02x", (unsigned)(unsigned char)a[0]);
```

Or specify its actual type as `unsigned char`:

```
printf("%02hhx", (unsigned char)a[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

(Type `char` is signed, sizeof(int) is 4, 8 bits per byte.)

Both operands of `a`, are promoted to `int`, because of integer promotions:

```
a[0]^a[1];
```

Because `a[1]` is a signed type, `char`, the number `0xa5` actually represents a negative value of -91. The representation of the value -91 in type `int` is `0xffffffa5`.

So the calculation becomes:

```
0x00000056 ^ 0xffffffa5
```

or in decimal:

```
86 ^ -91
```

The result is of that operation is:`0xfffffff3`

The unsigned char version of this calculations doesn't have this 'problem'.